# Can you temporarily disable mongoid relationships to roll your own queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, eager-loading

I am trying to manually build a series of queries to get around mongo's lack of joins and mongoids lack of eager loading.  Suppose I have 2 classes:

```
class A
include Mongoid::Document
has_many :bs
...

class B
include Mongoid::Document
belongs_to :a
...
```

If I run a query on bs:

```
bs = B.where(...)
```

The result is a MongoidCriteria

If i try to get the first b by calling bs.first, however, it immediately fires a mongo query for the a association. This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (If I have 1,000 b's, I'm trying to avoid 1000 singleton b queries).

This is fine, but when I have complex relationships, I want to work around the lack of eager loading by manually specifying the models myself, collecting ids, and the only returning the core  model, without the associations.

Is there anything that will let me do this? Something like:

```
bs = B.where(...).disable_automatic_association_queries
```

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 0):

The method is .without.  For example:

```
A.where(...).without(:bs)
```